# ReactJS and Konva free drawing with pencil, brush and eraser

Tags: reactjs, react-konva, konva, konvajs-reactjs

I want to create a simple app where I can choose between pencil, brush and eraser. I have Home.js and addLine.js. But there is a bug which I cant fix. When I change from brush back to pencil I'am drawing with the pencil but there is something like a border surrounding the pencil drawing which takes the color I previously used for the brush. [Sample bug pucture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eh0O6.png) If it matters I used react color for color picking.

```
const Home = () => {
 
  
  const stageEl = React.createRef();
  const layerEl = React.createRef();
  const [color, setColor] = useState('');

  
  return (
    <div className="home-page-div">
      <h1>This is the Home page!</h1>
    
      <button onClick= { () => addLine(stageEl.current.getStage(), layerEl.current, color, "pencil")}>Pencil</button>
     <button onClick={ () => addLine(stageEl.current.getStage(), layerEl.current, color, "brush")}>Brush</button>
      <button onClick={() => addLine(stageEl.current.getStage(), layerEl.current, color, "eraser")}>Erase</button>
      <CompactPicker 
      color={color} 
      onChange={(color)=>{setColor(color.hex)}}
      />       
      <Stage
        width={window.innerWidth * 0.9}
        height={window.innerHeight - 150}
        ref={stageEl}
      
      >
        <Layer ref={layerEl}>
        
        </Layer>
      </Stage>
    </div>
  )
};

export default Home;
```

and addLine

```
export const addLine = (stage, layer, color, mode) => {
  let isPaint = false;
  let lastLine;
 
  stage.on("mousedown touchstart", function(e) {
    isPaint = true;
    let pos = stage.getPointerPosition();
    lastLine = new Konva.Line({
      stroke:  `${color}`,
      strokeWidth:  mode === "brush" ? 8 : mode === "pencil" ? 1 : 10,
      globalCompositeOperation:
        mode === "eraser" ? 'destination-out' : 'source-over',
      points: [pos.x, pos.y],
      draggable: false,
    });
    layer.add(lastLine);
  });
  console.log(mode);
  console.log(color);
  stage.on("mouseup touchend", function() {
    isPaint = false;
  });
  stage.on("mousemove touchmove", function() {
    if (!isPaint) {
      return;
    }
    
  const pos = stage.getPointerPosition();
    let newPoints = lastLine.points().concat([pos.x, pos.y]);
    lastLine.points(newPoints);
    layer.batchDraw();
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

On button click, you are calling `addLine()` function:

```js
<button onClick= { () => addLine(stageEl.current.getStage(), layerEl.current, color, "pencil")}>Pencil</button>
```

Inside that function you are adding NEW even listeners:

```js
stage.on("mousedown touchstart", function(e) {
  // .. function
});
```

That means a new listener is added on every click. So when you click on another tool, the old one will still work.

Two fix the issue you can use two ways:

1. Listen to the stage event just once, and inside `addLine()` function just change the current attributes of current line. Similar to how it done in [Konva free drawing demo](https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Free_Drawing.html#page-title)
2. Or just remove all previous listeners inside `addLine()` function with [node.off() method](https://konvajs.org/docs/events/Remove_Event.html). But I don't recommend that approach as it may lead to bugs if you remove wrong listeners.